# When I change the value of overflow-scrolling from "touch" to " " in the ios11 devices, the screen splashed

Tags: css

change
`overflow-scrolling:"touch"`
to
`overflow-scrolling:""`
the screen splashed!
It confused me for a long time, anybody had ever solve this problem?